# Print the lines from a file which contains words given by the user

Tags: powershell

I want to type in words and the script prints the lines which contains the words.

I have the following data in the folder foods.txt

```
1;400;100000;pizza tea
11;178;56124;coke hamburger
7;777;20000;sprite pizza
10;150;100000;coke sandwich fries
```

So for example if I type in pizza, it prints out the first and the 3rd line:

```
1;400;100000;pizza tea
7;777;20000;sprite pizza
```

My script can filter for one word, but I don't know how to make it to filter for all the given words so if I type in: `tea fries`, it should print out the first and last line.

I was thinking of filtering the main file, then redirect it to another file, filter that file too, or something like that?

```
$word = Read-Host "Type in the words"
Copy-Item foods.txt first.txt

foreach ($i in Get-ChildItem *first.txt) {
    $filtered = Get-Content "foods.txt" | % {
        if ($_ -match "$word") {
            Write-Host $_
        }
    }
    $filtered >> second.txt
    Copy-Item second.txt first.txt
}
Get-Content second.txt
Remove-Item first.txt
Remove-Item first.txt
```

Comment: Your programming style is quite powershell unlike. To have the `-match` operator hit ether of the entered words put a `|` between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `foods.txt` file looks remarkably like a CSV file without headers to me..
This means you could also use the CSV parsing method to go about this:

```
# Import the file as CSV to get an array of objects.
# I'm just making up the headers here..
$foods = Import-Csv -Path 'foods.txt' -Delimiter ';' -Header 'ItemsSoldToday','ItemsSoldThisWeek','InStock','Description'

# Next, read the words typed in by the user, split on whitespace character(s) 
# and escape any characters that might have special meaning in a regular expression
$words = (Read-Host "Type in the words separated by a space character") -split '\s+' | ForEach-Object { [regex]::Escape($_) }
# Join these words together with a pipe symbol "|" that will make an 'OR' within the regex match
# and filter the objects that have any of these words in the 'Description' field
$chosen = $foods | Where-Object { $_.Description -match ($words -join '|') }

# Example: when the user types "tea fries", $chosen now contains an array of objects:
#
#   ItemsSoldToday ItemsSoldThisWeek InStock Description        
#   -------------- ----------------- ------- -----------        
#   1              400               100000  pizza tea          
#   10             150               100000  coke sandwich fries


# If you want the returned output to be exactly like the input text file, simply recombine the values
$chosen | ForEach-Object { $_.PSObject.Properties.Value -join ';' }
```

This will return:

```
1;400;100000;pizza tea
10;150;100000;coke sandwich fries
```

Comment: It is working, thank you, very nice and understandable.

Answer (score 1):

To filter by a list of words entered via `Read-Host` you need to split that input and build a regular expression from the tokens:

```
$words = Read-Host '...'
$re = ($words.Split() | Where-Object {$_} | ForEach-Object {[regex]::Escape($_)}) -join '|'
```

If your words don't contain characters that have a special meaning in regular expressions (like dots or square brackets), or you want them handled as regular expressions anyway, you can omit the step `| ForEach-Object {[regex]::Escape($_)}`.

Also, PowerShell comparison operators work as enumerators, so you can use them directly on arrays:

```
(Get-Content 'foods.txt') -match $re | Set-Content 'result.txt'
```